# One year review ban for deleting a rude edit from an off-topic post?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

As in the title I just realized to got this:

> Your review on
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20923486 wasn't
>   helpful. We do not need edits to spam.
>
> Come back on Sep 21 '19 at 10:32 to continue reviewing.

The post had this content:

> Please Help i need you to stop <--- TITLE
>
> can you stop down voting my autistic sons python help post he is real
>   upset and started to cry. please can you stop being toxic thanks <---
>   CONTENT

My edit has removed (*from a third user's edit if I remember well*) only the "**please can you stop being toxic thanks**" part, because IMHO on an off-topic post like this, that part was probably added only to increase the disagreement sense in that post, and this was totally useless and out of the "scope" (*with all the implicit nonsense contained in it, because without publishing the nicknames, how could we know who his sons are?*). So I would ask to the moderator (*who had applied this penalization*) the reasons, because I can't really understand. Specially about the "**We do not need edits to spam**" part on the message (SPAM o-O?!).

Comment: Why didn't you flag the post as spam? Because it really is spam.

Comment: I guess you chose "Improve Edit"? This accepts the original edit. Edits to Spam posts are useless and should be rejected.

Comment: The whole question was inappropriate to the site, so it simply cannot be improved through editing. Rejecting all edits on such questions is the right action.

Comment: Since you are new to meta: Voting on meta works different and will not have any influence on your reputation.

Comment: i really don't realized it was SPAM

Comment: @yivi yes I'm referring to reviews because of the tag :-). I remember that some months ago I received a 3 days ban for a wrong flag but I don't know if I had make some other mistake in the meantime.

Comment: After reviewing moderator Samuel Liew's answer, I can see that it is a good thing that you asked this question on meta, else you may have been inappropriately stuck with a long-term review ban. This question is definitely deserving of an up-vote.

Comment: Even without the definition of Spam on SO, you can avoid those with a simple rules. Don't edit crap. No turd polishing. There is no way this post can be on topics without OP editing a question or information in it. It's not related to programing, with this level of detail it almost eligible to Pets.se. Do not accept edit on Insult / Rant / Blatantly off-topic. There is Nothing to salvage in them.

Comment: Given your new to meta, I thought I'd direct you to consider changing the accepted answer to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374529/3956566). it was written after you accepted the current one. It's something I'm loathe to suggest, but it makes it clear it was a misclick and there's no other reason behind the lengthy ban.

Comment: @YvetteColomb agree, I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I must have had mixed up both suggested edit reviews on the same post via the revision history and applied the ban incorrectly to your edit which approved rev.3, when I originally had intended to ban the user who approved rev.2

Please accept my sincere apologies, I have lifted your review ban which was meant for another user.

However, if you see an spammy or rude/abusive post like this in the future, do flag it as such instead of trying to edit the post. As it was a review, the correct action would still be to decline the suggested edit, as there are more serious content issues with the post, and there is no way to salvage the post with an edit.

[image]

Comment: Two suggested edits completed through the reviews within 11 minutes? I'm lucky if I get one in half an hour

Comment: Thanks @Samuel I appreciate. Not as excuse but probably I was also tired and my mind has been misled seeing the approval of the previous edit :-) I will take a cup of coffee before each review session :)))

Comment: But shouldn't this be (using a medical term) a "Never Event"? A 1 year review ban is a harsh punishment to say the least, and before implementing such, there should be safeguards in place to avoid mistakes and errors such as has occurred, no? If not, then the moderators *should* clean house so that these safeguards (and any others) are in place, such as verification by a second moderator before any such harsh punishment is meted out.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The ability to come and appeal here on Meta - like the OP did here - is a safeguard of sorts, in fairness. I'll grant you that it's not an ideal one, though. Us regular Meta denizens are all invested enough in the site that if a mod treated us unfairly, we'd react by jumping on our Meta soapbox to protest the grand injustice of it all, but many users might respond by quietly walking away from the site and never coming back.

Comment: This immediately brings up the concern that we should be able to flag posts from within the review queues. The correct review approach here isn't even available!

Comment: Considering the number of flags you handle you make very few mistakes. With all the flags you handle and all the scripts you write, you make a such a good effort for us all on here. A public thank you :)

Answer (score 44):

That looks like a custom message. And yeah, "spam" isn't the best description for toxic content especially in light of the fact that Stack Overflow has a very clear definition of "spam" that excludes this sort of content.

But the point remains not to edit content that should be flagged as either spam or rude/abusive. This is pretty counter-intuitive but preserving the abusive content is necessary for the site's anti-spam (I know) measures to be effective. <del>The 1-year suspension is presumably because you've had review demerits in the past, and as far as the system is concerned you're continuing to make poor reviewing decisions.</del>

OK I went and looked at your history and apparently you've only had a handful of review bans up to a week long in the past. I don't know why the moderator who issued this ban felt compelled to escalate this all the way to a full year immediately after your last 2-day ban. I don't think that was necessary. I'll get it reduced or lifted.

Comment: For that I asked here, to understand where is the very grave error to deserve a 1 year ban. Thanks to all for the explanations!

Comment: @gp_sflover Not a "grave error" in terms of edit-approvals, we've seen much, much worse (i.e. approving edits that add spam links). :D

Comment: And yes, for an English novice like me is difficult to identify as SPAM a post like this because it don't contain links, ads or some other content that refers to external resources :-)

Comment: @gp_sflover It wasn't SPAM, but it wasn't a post that needed to be edited in any way. And your English level is more than sufficient to realize that post is not fit for the site.

Comment: @yivi in fact I flagged the post as off-topic but I don't know why, when I saw the pendent edit (by a third user), I thought to delete the named part  instead of move away :))

Comment: @gp_sflover: my own philosophy is to be very conservative with my edits, to only edit questions where my edit would be more than trivial, where it is a subject that I am fully confident in my knowledge of, where I know for a *fact* that my edit would be helpful. Otherwise, leave it alone.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels agree and I will apply the same concept for the future :-)

Answer (score 4):

Normally I wouldn't add onto the other answers, but they all focused on the mistaken 1 year ban. Let me address why your edit was terrible and at least worthy of some moderator intervention. Specifically I wanted to address your comment here

> i really don't realized it was SPAM

I believe you and, honestly, I wouldn't expect people who don't hang around spam all day to know this. People make junk posts like this infrequently, so it takes a few times of seeing them to know they're spam. But there's a question nobody has asked you yet, so I will ask it now...

## Why did you think this question needed editing?

I mean, this is what your final edit left it as

> Can you stop down-voting my autistic son's python help post? He is real upset and started to cry.

All you did was remove the last sentence about being toxic. But **the rest of the question was just as bad**. This isn't a question for SO. It's not a question period. What frustrates reviewers like myself is that someone created the initial edit in the first place. The one reviewer who got it right rejected it with this (emphasis mine)

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, **more accurate or more accessible**. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

There's two lessons you need to learn here

1. Edits are for **fixing questions that are salvageable**. There's nothing to salvage here. We tend to call it "turd polishing", because there are some people who relentlessly believe that anything can be edited into better shape, regardless of what the original material was. If you see a suggested edit that doesn't fix some problem with the question **reject it**. That was your mistake here. Had you done that, we wouldn't be here.
2. **Flag bad questions for closure.** I know it's not obvious, but you can suggest a question be closed if you have >15 rep. Next time you see this kind of thing in the queue, open the question in a separate tab and reject the edit, then flag this for closure. You're almost to 3k, so you'll soon be doing close reviews, but until then, get familiar with flagging them. The method to close vote is nearly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning behind your suspension is not in the very edit itself, but the post the edit was submitted for. Those posts are considered spam, and the only correct course of action when it comes to spam is to flag it as such, and move on.

Approving these edits would mean we approve of them, which we absolutely do not.

That's the sole reasoning needed for your suspension, albeit I'd like to think that it wasn't the only "bad" approval of yours in recent times, otherwhise the 1-year suspension might be a little bit harsh.

Comment: (splitting hairs) [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Comment: A 1 year ban isn't a "bit harsh".

Comment: @GhostCat You forgot my carefully planted "little" :( .. Jokes aside, I often use "might be a little bit" in situations where it definitely is not a little bit. Should probably stop that.